# 3 variable sequence sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sequence

So basically there are two sequences from I to j and j to k.
For example 3  to 5 and 5 to 2.
And we need to know the sum. 3 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2.
And my code is not working.

```
var arr = [];
var sum = 0;
```

function pushIn(i, j, k){

```
    for(var a = i; a < j; a++){
        arr.push(a);
    }

    for(var a = j; a == k; a--){
        arr.push(a);
    }
    for(var i = 0; i <arr.length;i++){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how are you invoking your function?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in your second for loop
Perhaps you should try this

```
for(var a = i; a < j; a++){
    arr.push(a);
}

for(var a = j; a > k; a--){
    arr.push(a);
}
for(var i = 0; i <arr.length;i++){
    sum += arr[i];
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In `for` loop, second argument is a comparator- *condition for executing the code block*.

In your second loop, condition is never met hence it does not iterate at all.

In your case, I am assuming you want loop to be iterated unless it is less than or equals to `k` hence you need to make it `>=` so that condition will meet andloop will be iterated.

```js
var arr = [];
var sum = 0;

function pushIn(i, j, k) {

  for (var a = i; a < j; a++) {
    arr.push(a);
  }
  for (var a = j; a >= k; a--) {
    arr.push(a);
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(pushIn(3, 5, 2));
```

Comment: Hey why condition in second loop never meet? With a-- it will eventually go from j = 5 to k thats 2?

Comment: No, It will never go as for the first iteration itself, condition fails hence loop does not go beyond that...

Answer (score 0):

You may use `.concat()` and `.reduce()` to get the resultant value:

```js
let reducer = (i, j, k) => [].concat(
    Array.from({length: j - (i - 1)}, (_, index) => i + index),
    Array.from({length: j - k},  (_, index) => j - (index + 1))
).reduce((r, c) => r + c, 0);

console.log(reducer(3, 5, 2));
```